# MySQL INNER JOIN duplicates one column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've got a table **user_log** where I store information about user activity, for example login and logout actions.
Table has four colums: **id**, **user_id**, **action** and **timestamp**

I would like to select all logout and login actions timestamps for some **user_id** in one result table, there would be columns like this:

**user_id** **login_timestamp** **logout_timestamp**.

I use this MySQL query:

```
SELECT 
    user_log.user_id,
    user_log_login.login_timestamp,
    user_log_logout.logout_timestamp
FROM
    user_log
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        user_id, timestamp as login_timestamp
    FROM
        user_log
    WHERE
        action = 'login successful') as user_log_login
ON
    user_log.user_id = user_log_login.user_id
INNER JOIN
   (SELECT 
        user_id, timestamp as logout_timestamp
    FROM
        user_log
    WHERE
        action = 'logout successful') as user_log_logout
ON
    user_log.user_id = user_log_logout.user_id
WHERE
    user_log.user_id = 4
```

But the result contains duplicates of **login_timestamp**.
Have a look:
[image]

Comment: Yes because you have more than one `logout_timestamp` for `user_id = 4`.

Comment: @MotoGP I have the same amount of login and logout timestamps. Select Distinct using with () gives me syntax error, but without brackets I've got the same issue as posted.

Comment: i think you would get a cross joined result for login and logout timestamp for a given user. You need to add more filter conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest another approach, a correlated query in the select :

```
SELECT t.user_id,t.timestamp Login_Time ,
       (SELECT s.timestamp FROM user_log s
        WHERE s.user_id = t.user_id and s.action = 'logout successful'
            AND s.timestamp > t.timestamp
        ORDER BY s.timestamp limit 1) as Logout_Time
FROM user_log t
WHERE t.user_id = 4 
    AND t.action = 'login successful'
```

This will basically select the next logout for each login and will be faster then selecting from the table 3 times.